# How to represent multiple steps in howPerformed property in SurgicalProcedure schema type in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am writing a schema of type `SurgicalProcedure` in which there are steps on how to perform surgery.
How should it be represented in JSON-LD format?

The property I want to use is `howPerformed`.

Here are the steps:

> Step 1:
> Cataractous Lens Removal
> Extracapsular Cataract Extraction
>
> In this procedure, the cataractous lens is broken up using either a laser (latest: AI-LenSx Femto) or using ultrasound waves (Phaco emulsification). The broken lens is then extracted through a tiny hollow tube. The normal lens capsule surrounding the lens is left intact.
>
> Intra-capsular Cataract Removal
>
> In this procedure, the cataractous lens is taken out as a whole by making a big incision cut on the eye then the incision is closed using 5 to 7 stitches. This procedure has become obsolete now.
>
> Step 2:
> Replacement for the Lens
> Once the lens is removed, it may be replaced by one of the three options:
>
> A contact lens, or
> Special cataract glasses with very powerful magnification.
> An intraocular lens (an artificial lens placed in the eye during cataract surgery)
> Latest Surgical Techniques for Cataract

I want to represent step1 and step2 along with substeps.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your doubt you can follow below procedure in JSON-LD format:

- The `SurgicalProcedure` has a name "Cataract Surgery" and it involves the property `howPerformed`, that contains an array of `MedicalProcedure` objects representing the steps of the surgery.
- Each `MedicalProcedure` has a name, description, and if possible, small sub-steps presented as an array of `MedicalProcedure` objects.
- Step 1 ("Cataractous Lens Removal") has two small sub-steps: "Extracapsular Cataract Extraction" and "Intra-capsular Cataract Removal".
- Step 2 ("Replacement for the Lens") has three small sub-steps: "Contact Lens", "Special Cataract Glasses", and "Intraocular Lens".

Code:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "SurgicalProcedure",
  "name": "Cataract Surgery",
  "howPerformed": [
    {
      "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
      "name": "Cataractous Lens Removal",
      "description": "The cataractous lens is broken up using either a laser (latest: AI-LenSx Femto) or using ultrasound waves (Phaco emulsification). The broken lens is then extracted through a tiny hollow tube. The normal lens capsule surrounding the lens is left intact.",
      "subSteps": [
        {
          "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
          "name": "Extracapsular Cataract Extraction",
          "description": "In this procedure, the cataractous lens is broken up using either a laser (latest: AI-LenSx Femto) or using ultrasound waves (Phaco emulsification). The broken lens is then extracted through a tiny hollow tube. The normal lens capsule surrounding the lens is left intact."
        },
        {
          "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
          "name": "Intra-capsular Cataract Removal",
          "description": "In this procedure, the cataractous lens is taken out as a whole by making a big incision cut on the eye then the incision is closed using 5 to 7 stitches. This procedure has become obsolete now."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
      "name": "Replacement for the Lens",
      "description": "Once the lens is removed, it may be replaced by one of the three options:",
      "subSteps": [
        {
          "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
          "name": "Contact Lens",
          "description": "A contact lens"
        },
        {
          "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
          "name": "Special Cataract Glasses",
          "description": "Special cataract glasses with very powerful magnification"
        },
        {
          "@type": "MedicalProcedure",
          "name": "Intraocular Lens",
          "description": "An artificial lens placed in the eye during cataract surgery"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Not gonna work that way. See https://schema.org/SurgicalProcedure. The property `howPerformed` only links `text`, not another `type`.  Instead, use `procedureType` and then link markup for `MedicalProcedureType`.

Comment: I did not down-vote. You are 50% there. Revise your answer following advice above. Validate your answer on SMV [https://validator.schema.org/]